# Summarise data frame ignoring repetition

Tags: r, summary

I have a data frame in which there are repetitions of entries  in one column. I want to summarize the other columns based on the that one column. I wish the summary to consider each unique entry and not the total count when making the summary.
For example in the data frame example below, if i want to answer the question on **how many people surveyed are young,midage and old?**  "RefID" 1-1 is taken as a count of 1 in summarising "ageclass"=young and not interpreted as a count of 5.

```
RefID   Altitude    Sex ageclass
1-1 Low F   young
1-1 Low F   young
1-1 Low F   young
1-1 Low F   young
1-1 Low F   young
1-2 Low F   midage
1-2 Low F   midage
1-2 Low F   midage
1-2 Low F   midage
1-2 Low F   midage
1-2 Low F   midage
1-2 Low F   midage
1-2 Low F   midage
1-2 Low F   midage
1-2 Low F   midage
1-2 Low F   midage
1-2 Low F   midage
1-3 Low F   old
1-3 Low F   old
1-3 Low F   old
1-3 Low F   old
1-3 Low F   old
1-3 Low F   old
1-3 Low F   old
1-3 Low F   old
1-3 Low F   old
1-3 Low F   old
1-3 Low F   old
1-3 Low F   old
1-3 Low F   old
1-3 Low F   old
1-3 Low F   old
1-3 Low F   old
1-3 Low F   old
1-3 Low F   old
1-4 Low F   old
1-4 Low F   old
1-4 Low F   old
1-4 Low F   old
1-4 Low F   old
1-4 Low F   old
1-4 Low F   old
1-4 Low F   old
1-4 Low F   old
1-4 Low F   old
1-4 Low F   old
1-4 Low F   old
1-5 Low F   old
1-5 Low F   old
1-5 Low F   old
1-5 Low F   old
1-5 Low F   old
1-5 Low F   old
1-5 Low F   old
1-7 Low F   old
1-7 Low F   old
1-7 Low F   old
1-7 Low F   old
1-8 Low F   old
1-8 Low F   old
1-9 Low F   old
1-9 Low F   old
1-9 Low F   old
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

To get unique entries in a dataframe, see ?uniqe :

```
Data <- unique(Mydata)
```

You can use by :

```
by(Data,Data$ageclass,summary)
```

See also `?summary` to understand the outcome. If you are interested in counts, you can use `table` ,eg :

```
table(Data$RefID,Data$ageclass)
```

or for a summary :

```
margin.table(table(Data$RefID,Data$ageclass),margin=2)
```

EDIT : 
you'll have to be a bit careful, as `unique()` takes the unique rows. If you have both a male and a female having refID 1-1 , then you'll still count it twice. But I presume that won't be the case in your data. If you really want to make sure, you can do :

```
with(unique(Data[c(1,4)]),margin.table(table(RefID,ageclass),margin=2))
```

or take the `plyr` solution mentioned here.

Answer (score 2):

The `plyr` package is useful for this. E.g. you could do:

```
> require(plyr)
> ddply( df, .(ageclass), summarise, Num = length(unique(RefID)))
  ageclass Num
1   midage   1
2      old   6
3    young   1
```

Comment: Thanks Prasad, your response was quick and the solution worked!!

Comment: How can i for example get the number of young, midage and old for each sex(F/M)? Thanks

Comment: Found the solution to my question                               ddply( df, .(ageclass,Sex), summarise, Num = length(unique(RefID)))                                                            Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With `subset` you make a subset of the data and with `duplicated` you get a logical vector indicating if a value already occured in a vector. First a small sample dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(
   ID=rep(1:5,each=5),
   attitude="low",
   sex=c(rep("F",10),rep("M",15)),
   age=c(rep("young",5),rep("middle",10),rep("old",10))
   )
```

Then you can make a subset in which only the first time each ID is entered is recorded:

```
df.sub <- subset(df,!duplicated(df$ID))
```

Then you can summarize:

```
> summary(df.sub$age)
middle    old  young 
     2      2      1
```