# R: remove rows with same in all columns

Tags: r, row

Input file:

```
y <- read.table(textConnection('
   c1   c2   c3
1  a    b    -1
2  a    b    -1
3  a    c    1
4  a    b    1
5  a    b    -1
'), header=TRUE)
```

thus, y is

```
  c1 c2 c3
1  a  b -1
2  a  b -1
3  a  c  1
4  a  b  1
5  a  b  -1
```

the output file would be:

```
  c1 c2 c3
1  a  b -1
3  a  c  1
4  a  b  1
```

How to remove multiple or duplicate rows with same entry in all columns?

Comment: see also eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016418/summarise-data-frame-ignoring-repetition , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626567/collapsing-data-frame-by-selecing-one-row-per-group

Answer (score 9):

Try `unique(y)`

```
> unique(y)
  c1 c2 c3
1  a  b -1
3  a  c  1
4  a  b  1
```

Answer (score 3):

?unique. Watch out for floating point variables though...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `unique()`, `duplicated()` is also helpful for identifying which rows are duplicates.

For example:

```
subset(y, !duplicated(y))
```

But as Chase and Nick show, `unique()` is what you are looking for here and is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use distinct() from the dplyr package

```
> library(dplyr, quietly = T)
> distinct(y)
  c1 c2 c3
1  a  b -1
2  a  c  1
3  a  b  1
```